# Selenium. Login on website with saved passwords in browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a lot of logins and passwords saved in my FireFox. I am using selenium and  I want to select my saved users to login on website. I specify my profile and selenium correctly create temp profile with kye3.db and logins.json files when I run it. But after that I dont dont know how to login with saved logins, when I type logins in input form nothing is happend, looks like it doesnt see my saved passwords. (When I type my logins in FF without selenium it propose me to select one of the saved users and fill password automaticaly)

Answer (score 0):

There is a little work around that were you can create classes with all you passwords and userNames and just write the logic that toogles a certain password for a certain user like- X:username toogle X:password,  Y:username toogle Y:password etc. Hope the logic helps. Note Selenium works on how you implement logic so as any software. Always start basic.